# Pulling specific data from main sheet into a seperate one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull particular data from the main sheet, into a separate sheet.

It was a gym membership database, and we have staff, student and public members. They fill in a sheet online which automatically gets submitted into the database.

What I want to do is have all the rows that have answered 'public' into a sheet specifically for public members and the same for both staff and student members.

[image: Picture of spreadsheet]

Any advice on the best way to do that would be great

Comment: Looks like some vba might be in order

Comment: Those little triangles in the column headers are filters.  Select just the value you want in the first column (like "public").  Everything else will be hidden.  Then copy and paste.  Rinse & repeat for the next value.

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue can be solved by using a Helper Column along source data in Main Sheet.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Source data range in **MainSheet** is 
  `A3:D12`.
- Enter desire Criteria in Cell `A2` of 
  **OtherSheet**.
- Enter this Formula in Cell `E3` of **Main 
  Sheet.**

  `=IF(D3<>OtherSheet!$A$2,"",IF(D3=OtherSheet!$A$2,1+MAX($E$2:E2)))`
- Fill Formula down.
- Enter this Formula in Cell `A4` of 
  **OtherSheet**, then fill Right & Down.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(MainSheet!A$3:D$12,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),MainSheet!$E$3:$E$12,0)),"")`

**N.B.**

- Criteria **Public** in `OtherSheet's` Cell `A2` 
  makes the Formula versatile, since as soon you 
  replace **Public** with **Staff** or
  **Student**, the Formula will filter data 
  accordingly.

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*